# What is $ hashing? (dollar sign)

Tags: javascript, php, encryption

I saw a few encryption patterns and get information.

example

SHA-256 → $5$

SHA-512 → $6$
Refer:https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php
Which algorithm using is $P$?

Comment: SHA256 is not an encryption algorithm. Also, is this a JS or a PHP problem?

Comment: Just to note, hashing and encryption are not the same thing. Sha256 is a hashing algorithm

Comment: Thank you for teaching me
But I know that. Next, let's clarify the definition.

Comment: "*But I know that*" - "*Let's clarify the definition*". Unsure what you mean with this, if you knew this then you would know a hash is irreversible, meaning there is no mechanism in place to revert the hash back to the original value, but an encrypted string is decrypt-able/reversible. Furthermore, you've edited the title of your question but the content itself still mentions "* a few encryption patterns*"

Answer (score 3):

> Which algorithm using is $P$?

The **Portable PHP password hashing framework**, https://www.openwall.com/phpass/, generates hashes starting with `$P$`.

It has been used by systems / frameworks such as WordPress and Joomla in the past (but I couldn't say if those are still using it today.)